# Setting Ubound value in a dynamic array in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I've searched all over but am unable to get the answer I am seeking.  My question is:  Can a variable be used to set the Ubound value in a dynamic array in excel?  I have attempted to create a score sheet.  The user is prompted for the number of players.  I want to use the users response to be the Upper limit of my array.  Thank you in advanced for any assistance.

Comment: Yes, you can, but if it's a multidemsional array, you can only change the last dimension.

Comment: It is a one dimensional array

Comment: if you dont want to erase the data in the array, use `Redim Preserve`

Answer (score 1):

Why not test?

```
Sub test()
    Dim V As Variant
    Dim n As Long

    n = 10
    ReDim V(1 To n)
    Debug.Print UBound(V) 'prints 10
End Sub
```

Comment: I'll try and get back with you on how it goes.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes you can.**

First declare the array. and `ReDim` it.

Like

```
Dim arr() as Variant
Dim vari as Integer

'Some code to get the variable.
 vari = 10

ReDim Preserve arr(vari)
```

`Preserve` is Used if you do not want to change the Data that is Already there in the Array.